# Is it possible to create one index for both primary and foreign key?

Tags: sql

Let's suppose we have two tables `A` and `B` and between them one-to-one relation.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A 
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS B 
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES A(ID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

`B.ID` key will be used as foreign key in tables about which `A` doesn't know. When row is deleted from `A` there also will be deletion from other tables that are linked to `B`. As we see in `B` one column is at the same time primary and foreign key. As I know keys use indexes. So, is it possible to make these two keys use the same index? Does it depend on RDBMS? Or there is something wrong in my understanding?

Comment: In all relational databases, the primary key is backed by a unique index. you you have an index aon `b.id` there is nothing you need to do. The fact that it's also a foreign key doesn't change that. After all the column only exists once

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do I understand you right - in my example PK and FK in `B` will use the same index?

Comment: A foreign key doesn't "use" an index. It's just a foreign key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I'm not 100% sure that is always true.  It is definitely true in databases that support unique indexes.  In those that don't, I can't think off-hand of any that enforce primary key constraints (Hive, Redshift, BigQuery, Vertica, for instance).  That said, it is within the realm of possibility for a database to have primary keys without a unique index, as that would normally be understood.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: well some DBMS just pretend to create primary (or even foreign) keys and simply "store" them for documentation purposes (I think Redshift does). But they never enforce them, so I wouldn't actually count them as "primary keys" to begin with. Only if the primary (or unique) key is actually enforced by the DBMS, I would consider it a primary key. And I don't think there is any product that doesn't do this with a unique index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I know [foreign] keys use indexes

This is false.  I am guessing that your experience with databases is limited to MySQL/MariaDB.  These are two databases where a foreign key definition *does* created an index on the referencing table.

In most databases, a foreign key definition does NOT create an index on the referencing table.  Another difference is that most databases (and I'm pretty sure the standard as well) requires that the referenced key be either a primary key or unique key.  That doesn't affect you in this case, but it is another deviation from the standard in MySQL in this area.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I learned FK and indexes when I worked with MySQL. Do I understand you right, that for example H2 and PostgreSql when they create FK constraint they don't create index for this FK?

Comment: @Pavel_K . . . Postgres does not.  I cannot speak to H2.  Also, I don't think that MySQL would create two indexes in this case.  The designers recognized this issue and will use an existing index if available.